# Formatting the printing of elements from a list of tuples

Tags: python, formatting, format, python-3.6

Below is one instance of an element within a list that I am working to format and print.

```
[(1, [2, 'A', 4, 5, 6], ...)
```

Due to the tuples inside of the elements, I have ran into problems formatting. I am attempting to print this output in plain text, as is:

```
A(1) 5 6 2
```

Any help would be much appreciated and if you know of any good teaching resources to learn more about formatting print statements, please feel free to share them! Note: 1, 2, 4, 5 and 6 are `int` types and 'A' is a string. Also, there are 10 of these I have to print, but they should be printed in the same form, ex:

```
A(1) 5 6 2

A(1) 5 6 2

A(1) 5 6 2
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Comment: It is really not clear to me how you get from `[(1, [2, 'A', 4, 5, 6], ...)` to `A(1) 5 6 2`. What happened to `2` and `4` and why don't you want to see them? And why do you want the order `5 6 2` when the data is in the sequence `2 5 6`?